# Limits of trig multivariable Integration Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Solve
$$\int_0^1\int_0^u(tan^2x+y)^{1\over2}dxdy$$
where $0<u<{\pi\over2}$

My attempt was to use Fubini's thm, but when I solved this
$$\int_0^{\pi\over2}\int_0^1(tan^2x+y)^{1\over2}dydx$$
I got a few undefined terms. I assume my limits of integeration is wrong, but i cannot understand  why.

Comment: the limit is certainly wrong (why did $u$ turn into \frac{\pi}{2}$? That being said, im not sure how to do this. the antiderivatives are terrible pretty much anyway you do it